# Starting event handler and class on a new thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I have two class, one is the main class and other is Bluetooth class.

Bluetooth class has methods for scanning for BLE devices, send data to the Bluetooth devices and event handler if one of the BLE devices sends data.

In the main class, once I determine the number of BLE devices around me, I loop through them and try to get some information. So basically, in the loop I have to wait until I finish communication with the BLE device. Since I'm running this on my main thread, application becomes un-responsive.

I would like to start my Bluetooth class on a different thread. How will I proceed?

Will creating Bluetooth class on a Runnable method, will make my blbuetooth class's event handler to run on a new thread?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know Android, but usually an object with "handler" in its name is something that you _register_ with the framework.  You say to the framework, "Here's my X object, please call its Y method next time/every time event Z happens."  Then, in any modern framework, when it calls your method, that happens in some thread that the framework created for its own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for `HandlerThread`, `Thread` and `Looper` and `ThreadPoolExecutor` for options.  Creating just the `Runnable` will not start a new thread for you.